# May 2017 CU for SharePoint 2013 adding Maintenance logs library

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, update

"May 2017 CU for SharePoint 2013 product family" CU update adding Maintenance log library to the existing site. The library has the log file.

Answer (score 2):

MaintenanceLogs library is old features which is there since sharepoint 2013 ( i believe). this library store the logs file related to site collection upgrade and you can access it via `https://sitexcollectionurl/_catalogs/MaintenanceLogs`.

[Review site collections upgraded to SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219531.aspx)